# Implementing new Snapping in ArcGIS Engine C# Application?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine

As I can find, there are two kinds of snapping in ArcGIS 10.2.2:

1- Classic snapping.

2- New ArcGIS Snapping, which doesn't have any specific name as I know.

I can't implement the New ArcGIS snapping in an ArcGIS Engine application. As I have read, it is completely available in ArcGIS Engine library but I can't make it work. The following is the code I'm working on :

```
IHookHelper2 m_hookHelper2 = new HookHelperClass
 {
       Hook = mapMain.Object
 } as IHookHelper2;
 IExtensionManager extensionManager = m_hookHelper2.ExtensionManager;

 if (extensionManager != null)
 {
      UID guid = new UIDClass();
      guid.Value = "{E07B4C52-C894-4558-B8D4-D4050018D1DA}";
      IExtension extension = extensionManager.FindExtension(guid);
     ISnappingEnvironment m_SnappingEnvironment = extension as 
                ISnappingEnvironment;
     m_SnappingEnvironment.SnappingType = 
                esriSnappingType.esriSnappingTypeEdge | 
                esriSnappingType.esriSnappingTypeEndpoint;
     m_SnappingEnvironment.Enabled = true;
     m_SnappingEnvironment.ShowSnapTips = true;
     m_SnappingEnvironment.SnapTipType = 
                esriSnappingTipType.esriSnappingTipLayerName;
     ISnappingFeedback m_SnappingFeedback = new SnappingFeedbackClass();
     m_SnappingFeedback.Initialize(null, m_SnappingEnvironment, true);

     if (m_SnappingFeedback != null)
     {
           m_SnappingFeedback.Refresh(0);
     }
 }
```

I should mention again that I want to implement New ArcGIS Snapping not the classic one.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/55768071/820534

Comment: Perhaps https://community.esri.com/thread/60078 would help. It seems you need to put the instantiation of the IHookHelper2 in the OnCreate function so that the application is *fully baked* at the time you need to grab the hook.